# how can we replace numeric digits from a series of strings?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls', skiprows = 17, skipfooter = 38)
energy.drop(energy.iloc[:, :2], inplace = True, axis = 1)
energy = energy.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2' : 'Country', 'Petajoules': 'Energy Supply', 'Gigajoules': 'Energy Supply per Capita', '%' : '% Renewable'})
energy[['Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']]= energy[['Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']].replace('...', np.NaN)
energy['Energy Supply'] = energy['Energy Supply']*1000000
energy['Country']
```

output -

```
0                                            Afghanistan
1                                                Albania
2                                                Algeria
3                                         American Samoa
4                                                Andorra
5                                                 Angola
6                                               Anguilla
7                                    Antigua and Barbuda
8                                              Argentina
9                                                Armenia
10                                                 Aruba
11                                            Australia1
12                                               Austria
13                                            Azerbaijan
14                                               Bahamas
15                                               Bahrain
16                                            Bangladesh
17                                              Barbados
18                                               Belarus
19                                               Belgium
20                                                Belize
                             ...                        
197                                        **Switzerland17**
198                                 Syrian Arab Republic
199                                           Tajikistan
200                                             Thailand
                             ...
Name: Country, dtype: object
```

i want to remove numeric value from strings that have numeric value in the end. How do i do that?

Comment: Use `energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace('\d', '')`